# In BigQuery, "where" clause with array-column of null values causing issue

Tags: google-bigquery

This is a follow-up of [BigQuery - Compute 0 - 100 percentiles for multiple columns, over multiple groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65211884/bigquery-compute-0-100-percentiles-for-multiple-columns-over-multiple-group) which was posted last year. The question is related to computing 0-100 percentiles for multiple columns in a table. Here's a reproducible example below. The post appears long but it is mostly reproducible example + screenshots of output to help resolve the issue:

```
with
    raw_data as (
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.9167 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8571 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.7778 as ft2Pct, 0.0 as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8125 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.5625 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.6842 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.7317 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8333 as ft2Pct, 0.5 as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8000 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.7500 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, 1.0 as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.6944 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.7500 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8571 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.9091 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.6667 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8261 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8108 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.7895 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8571 as ft2Pct, 1.0 as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.7727 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8333 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.6923 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8571 as ft2Pct, 1.0 as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.9268 as ft2Pct, 1.0 as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.7660 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8571 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, 0.8333 as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8636 as ft2Pct, 1.0 as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8036 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.9000 as ft2Pct, null as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct union all
        select 24997 as competitionId, 0.8108 as ft2Pct, 1.0 as ft3Pct, null as ftTechPct, null as ftFlagPct
    ),


  -- A) Positive Percentiles
  -- A1) compute quantiles: will be saved in messy arrays
  positive_pctile_arrays as (
    select
      competitionId
      ,approx_quantiles(ft2Pct, 10) as ft2Pct
      ,approx_quantiles(ft3Pct, 10) as ft3Pct
      ,approx_quantiles(ftTechPct, 10) as ftTechPct
      ,approx_quantiles(ftFlagPct, 10) as ftFlagPct
    from raw_data
    group by 1
  ),

  -- A2) and unnest arrays
  positive_pctiles as (
    select
      competitionId
      ,pctile
      ,ft2Pct
      ,ft3Pct
      ,ftTechPct
      ,ftFlagPct
    from positive_pctile_arrays as a
      ,a.ft2Pct with offset as pctile
      ,a.ft3Pct with offset as ft3PctPctile
      ,a.ftTechPct with offset as ftTechPctPctile
      ,a.ftFlagPct with offset as ftFlagPctPctile
    where
      pctile = ft3PctPctile  and 
      pctile = ftTechPctPctile  and 
      pctile = ftFlagPctPctile
  )

-- select * from raw_data
select * from positive_pctile_arrays
-- select * from positive_pctiles
```

A few comments:

- We are grouping by `competitionId` because our full data has >1 competitionId, even though the example has only 1.
- We want to compute 0 - 100 percentiles for these values, however for this example, we use `approx_quantiles(., 10)` instead of `approx_quantiles(., 100)` for brevity.

In our data, all values for `ftFlagPct` are null. As a result, in **A1** `positive_pctile_arrays`, the `ftFlagPct` column is blank.

[image]

Because of this, when we try to unnest these arrays in **A2**, it looks like the `where` clause filters all of the rows away. If you uncomment `select * from positive_pctiles`, this final output table will be empty.

If we comment `ftFlagPct` out from both **A1** and **A2**, we mostly get the unnested table that we want:

[image]

Our desired output is this table, with an additional column for `ftFlagPct` that has all null values. It seems we need the query to detect that the `ftFlagPct` array-column in `positive_pctile_arrays` is null / empty, and then somehow handle the left join differently?

**Edit:** We are working on a solution where we identify and replace the null-array with an array of dummy values (e.g, all 999999), and then replace the 999999's with nulls in the final output. Will post answer if we can resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

So, replacing

```
approx_quantiles(ftFlagPct, 10)
```

with

```
,case
    when array_length(approx_quantiles(ftFlagPct, 10)) is null then generate_array(999990, 1000000, 1)
    else approx_quantiles(ftFlagPct, 10)
end as ftFlagPct
```

...works to the extent that the final output table is retained (not filtered to 0 rows), with the 11 values 999990, 999991, ..., 1000000 in the `ftFlagPct` column. We don't love this solution by any means, but it gives us something to work with, and we can now easily replace these values with `null` values. Very open to a cleaner answer!

And then we can simply add `,case when ftFlagPct > 999989 then null else ftFlagPct end as ftFlagPct` to the select statement of the last query...

**Edit:** this throws an error for types == float, and our data has a combo of floats and ints, so we're still working on this.